# ggplot2 to plotly- Only shows traces and not data on the tooltip

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have taken my `plot1` plot and converted it to an interactive plot using `ggplotly()`, but when I try and use the tooltip, all it shows is the "Trace 1", "Trace 2" etc. for the 5 rectangles I have drawn with `geom_text` within my original plot. How do I get the tooltip to actually show the data when I hover over the data point rather than showing "Trace 1", "Trace 2" etc. ?

Here's my code:

```
    plot1 <- ggplot(dfplot, aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_text(aes(x=200, y=min(dfplot[,1]-3), label="Weak"), size=4)+
      geom_text(aes(x=400, y=min(dfplot[,1]-3), label="Strong"), size=4)+
      geom_text(aes(x=600, y=min(dfplot[,1]-3), label="Very Strong"), size=4) + ...
    finalplot1 <- ggplotly(plot1)
```

I want the plotly version to stop saying 'trace 1" in the tooltip and start showing the x and y coordinate values from the dataframe. How do I do this?

Comment: Please provide an extract from your dfplot data frame. I can't reproduce your problem from my own test data at all - the tool tips work as expected when I try it out with some dummy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So below is the regular scatter plot example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
lol <- ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat,y = price)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(lol)
```

This is how you can customize the tooltip.Remember also to add ,tooltip=c("text") like below.

```
lol2 <- ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat,y = price)) + geom_point(aes(text=paste('<br>cut:',cut)))

ggplotly(lol2,tooltip = c("text"))
```